# How to get the video upload date with YouTube API V3?

Tags: api, youtube

I know how can I get the video duration and views, like that

```
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id=hqepb5hzuB0&key={YOUR-API-KEY}");
$json_data = json_decode($JSON, true);
echo $json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'];
```

But how can I get the video upload date?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: is solution for that still not found?

Comment: Just answered my question below

Answer (score 0):

```
$vidkey = "Gsc7_E5HewM" ; //for example 
$apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ;
$dur = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=$vidkey&key=$apikey");


//----- duration---
$VidDuration =json_decode($dur, true);
foreach ($VidDuration['items'] as $vidTime)     
{           
$VidDuration= $vidTime['contentDetails']['duration']; 
}


// Check if $VidDuration is ISO string so the video is ready
if (is_string($VidDuration)){   
    //convert duration from ISO to M:S
    $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');     
    $date->add(new DateInterval($VidDuration));
    $vid_durH= $date->format('H') ; 
    if ($vid_durH=="00") {
        $vid_dur= $date->format('i:s') ;
    }
    else { 
        $vid_dur= $date->format('H:i:s') ;  
    } 
} 
else { 
    $vid_dur ="error" ;     
} 


$JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$vidkey&key=$apikey");      
$json_data = json_decode($JSON, true);      
$uploadDate = $json_data['items'][0]['snippet']['publishedAt'];         
$uploadDate = strtotime($uploadDate);
$uploadDate= date("F j, Y", $uploadDate); 

echo $vid_dur ;
```

Comment: The poster was asking for date UPLOADED, not polished. For many basic users this may be the same. However, for many businesses who upload weeks before publish date, these are two very different pieces of data. It's very unfortunate that JSON does not include both values. This has been a huge headache for my work, personally, as I need to keep track of both dates. YouTube HAS this info somewhere in their system, as you can view Analytics by "Upload Date", but it doesn't show up in the JSON feed. I'm trying to figure a workaround.